# Google cloud app engine - How to edit code using SSH and debug-mode

Tags: shell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to debug an application I have deployed to google cloud app engine. Reading the docs, I figured out that in order to do so I have to enter the debug mode using

```
gcloud app --project [Project ID] instances enable-debug
```

afterwards I am able to SSH into my instance and access root. Now I would like to edit some of the files. However, trying to use vim or nano does not seem to work.

Is there a way to edit those files without re-deploying the entire app?

Comment: Similar to @paing answer. Detailed steps in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846714/2179456

Answer (score 2):

Once you SSH into the App Engine instance and open a shell into the Docker container, you'll need to download the package list before installing nano or vim:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install nano
```

Then you can edit your app's files (which are in `/app`):

```
nano composer.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The deployed app runs live code. It is not generally feasible to edit it. Moreover, changes made to the running container are not permanent; in fact they and are lost at the first re-start. 
You may find some information on the [Debugging an Instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance) page. 
Unrelated to the above, an actual [command-line editor](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/10/introducing-Google-Cloud-Shels-new-code-editor.html) is offered in the cloud shell.