# Google Cloud App Engine - Edit 1 file

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new at Google Cloud and I would like to know if there is a way to edit only one file inside of an App Engine application.

This is my problem:
I am migrating from a normal hosting to google cloud and I am having some problems with my PHP code, I am using the same version like locally but I am getting some error in the cloud, so I need to change 1 or 2 files, update them and test the app, so is there any way to change that file directly on the server? To deploy i am using this command:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

But it takes about 10 minutes to deploy so is too slow my testing. Any suggestions?

Thanks.
Leandro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the standard environment the answer is no, you need to deploy a new version of the app to modify a file. So the advice would be - make the most of testing your app locally. See somehow related [Google AppEngine - updating my webapp after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239080/google-appengine-updating-my-webapp-after-deploy/42239602#42239602)

For the flexible environment (possibly your case as you mentioned 10 min deployment time, typical for the flexible env) there *might* be stuff to try, but tedious, see [Google AppEngine - updating my webapp after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239080/google-appengine-updating-my-webapp-after-deploy/42239602#42239602)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will use the Google Compute Engine instead Engine App so I can work faster. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to edit directly into the instance.

ssh into your instance and then start shell on your running docker as guided in this url. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance

After login you can see your `php` source files.

Basically you will not have any editor. So do

```
$> apt update
$> apt install nano
$> nano index.php // edit your files
```

you can see something like

[image]

Comment: ssh is not available for "Standard" App Engine projects.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change 1-2 files on the server so that it would update the app. Deployment is the process of updating the live app. If you want some changes to be made to the app that is already deployed, you will have to redeploy - there is no way around it. This is why it is recommended to [test the app locally before (re)deploying](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/testing-and-deploying-your-app) so that you are sure everything is working fine.

If locally everything works fine and issues start happening only when the app is deployed, this should be investigated further and I would advise you to open a new question and provide as much details as possible regarding the problems, including full stack trace of the error, related code parts, your app.yaml contents as well.

Comment: Performing 'asked by the author' kind of actions are pretty nasty but definitely possible!