# Create new instances of a Google App Engine Service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine Java 11 service using the Standard Environment.

I have deployed it specifying in the corresponding `app.yaml` file manual scaling, setting the number of instances to 1.

**Is there a way that I can increase the number of instances for this service without having to upload again all the files in the service?**

**So I have one instance. Now I want 2 instances. How do I do this?**

Have not found a way in either the console or in the gcloud utilities to do this.
Also, just calling `gcloud app deploy` with the modified `app.yaml` file creates a broken version of the service.

`app.yaml:`

```
service: headergrabber
runtime: java11
instance_class: B8

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Comment: You need to [redeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431750/google-cloud-app-engine-edit-1-file) your application whenever you want to make code changes in it. Please provide your original and modified `app.yaml` without including sensitive information such as API keys or password so we can check where the problem is.

Comment: Don't want to make any code changes. Code is fine. Just want more instances.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REST API to [patch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch) the number of instances of your manual scaling app.

Here's the HTTP request:

```
PATCH https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/{name=apps/*/services/*/versions/*}
```

You will have to pass [`manualScaling.instances`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions#manualscaling) field to update to the number of instance you prefer.

Here's an example with `curl` using a token that should only be used for local testing. I tested it on my side and it works:

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{ 'manualScaling': {  'instances': 2 } }" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/PROJECT-ID/services/SERVICE/versions/VERSION?updateMask=manualScaling.instances
```

Where:

- PROJECT_ID = Project ID
- SERVICE = Service Name
- VERSION = Version Name

You need to login to your account and set the project if you're using Cloud SDK or you can run the command on [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell).

An alternative is to use a [client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-appengine/v1) so you can write applications that can update your App Engine instance.

Take note that doing this would require App Engine Admin API **enabled** on your project. This API provides programmatic access to several of the App Engine administrative operations that are found in the Google Cloud Console.